# C++ read data from files

Tags: c++, readfile

Let's say I have a .txt file with this data in it:

```
1 Lipton 2  
2 CocaCola 2.5  
3 Pepsi 2
```

The ID for each item is before it and the price is after.
After I read the file and it works, how should I do if I want to choose the ID 2 and display it's price multiplied by 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: check the following link which is how to read files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line

Comment: You must *store* the information. Try it and get back to us if you have trouble.

Comment: Read the file into a `std::map` that maps from the ID number to a struct that contains the name and price.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file struct space separated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to store the data into a `std::vector`:

```
class Drink
{
    unsigned int id;
    std::string  name;
    double       price;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Drink& d);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Drink& d)
{
    input >> d.id;
    input >> d.name;
    input >> d.price;
    return input;
}
```

Your input code would like like this:

```
std::ifstream drink_file("drinks.txt");
std::vector<Drink> database;
Drink d;
while (drink_file >> d)
{
    database.push_back(d);
}
```

You could search the `database` for a drink with ID==2:

```
size_t quantity = database.size();
for (size_t index = 0; index < quantity; ++index)
{
    if (database[index].id == 2)
    {
       // Do something with record ID 2.
       break;
    }
}
```